# How to make a NSOperationQueue stack AsynchronousRequests

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

Here's my problem. Im using

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:_queue completionHandler:
^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}];
```

to send a request to the server. The queue is the same for every request since the class that does this is a singleton. The thing is in a certain point i am sending a second request before the first one finished and i want it to wait for the first one to finish, so what i want is a way to make the queue serial. The second request should still be asynchronous, so even tho it waits I want the main thread to keep running so the user can interact with the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on the `_queue` to `1` to limit the queue to only executing a single operation at a time.